# Automating access to Odyssey repository during a software deployment / release

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We are evaluating Odyssey as our software deployment and release tool for future. Part of the process would be to migrate the current SVN repository to Odyssey.

Is it possible to automate the extraction of the most current version of the various artifacts in the release, something like a API or Shell utility.

Comment: What would this extract do that `svn export` doesn't do?

Comment: Just to clarify as part of migration to Odyssey, my understanding from the documentation is that the SVN repository is totally migrated to Odyssey.

Comment: I am not aware that SVN commands would still be functional in a Odyssey environment.  I was unable to find what I was looking for on the web or on the site of the company that made Odyssey -  http://www.pantheon-inc.com/index.php/product/odyssey-change-management

Comment: Are you asking for help with Odyssey, or Subversion? You've tagged this exclusively with Subversion-related tags.

Comment: I am asking for help with Odyssey.  Odyssey tag wasn't available.